# Route with name 'na......' does not exist. $router.push() go to wrong path Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, router, vue-router

I faced to problem with incorrectly work method **$router.push()** in vue-router.

I have two pages which have same buttons and these buttons execute same methods (go to page addToMyLibrary page). Below I describe how these methods work

**Method:** **router.push()**,  I use **this.$route.name** in order to change dynamicly name property inside push() (need to change between `route.name: 'sectionDocs.search.addToMyLibrary'` and `route.name: 'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary'` according to current page).

When we locate on the page `/sectionDocs/search/:documentId`  after execute this *method* we go to the page `path: '/sectionDocs/search/addToMyLibrary/:documentId'` , but when I use this *method* on the page `path: 'sectionDocs/:documentId',` after executing method router go to wrong page which has wrong **$route.name**. Instead of getting `name:'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary'` we get dynamic path in name of route, I mean page has `$route.name: ':documentId'` and of course Route with name :documentId does not exist in vue-router.

I need to go to the page `/sectionDocs/search/:documentId/addToMyLibrary/:documentId` with `$route.name: 'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary'`, but I can`t solve the problem. Please anybody help me !

One more I can go to the page `$route.name: 'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary'`  only if enter right path in the url `/sectionDocs/search/:documentId/addToMyLibrary/:documentId`

Bellow I put my code

```
methods: {
  add_to_library() {
    this.$router.push({
      name: this.$route.name + '.addToMyLibrary',
      params: {
        documentId: this.document.documentItemId,
        documentType: 'LoremIpsum',
      }
    });
  },
}

<template>
  <button @click="add_to_library">Add to library</button>
</template>
```

router:

```
export default {
  path: 'sectionDocs',
  component: sectionDocs,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    title: 'SectionDocuments'
  },
  children: [{
    path: '/',
    component: sectionDocsSearch,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    children: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'sectionDocs',
      component: sectionDocsDefault,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
    }, {
      path: 'search',
      name: 'sectionDocs.search',
      component: sectionDocsSearchResults,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: 'addToMyLibrary',
          component: {
            render: h => h('router-view')
          },
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
          },
          children: [                
            {
              path: 'success',
              name: 'sectionDocs.search.addToMyLibrary.success',
              component: successfulAddMessage,
              meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
              }
            },{
              path: ':documentId',
              name: 'sectionDocs.search.addToMyLibrary',
              component: sectionDocsAddToLibrary,
              meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    }]
  }, {
    path: ':documentId',
    name: 'sectionDocs.view',
    component: sectionDocsView,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      dynamicRoute: true
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'addToMyLibrary',
        component: {
          render: h => h('router-view')
        },
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true
        },
        children: [              
          {
            path: 'success',
            name: 'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary.success',
            component: successfulAddMessage,
            meta: {
              requiresAuth: true
            }
          },{
            path: ':documentId',
            name: 'sectionDocs.view.addToMyLibrary',
            component: sectionDocsAddToLibrary,
            meta: {
              requiresAuth: true
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    ],
  }]
};
```